# Android Studio Sqlite Importar método delete erro

Tags: android

Não está deletando a tabela referente ao banco de de dados o Android Studio não aponta nenhum erro ao clicar no botão o programa não faz nada

(NA ACTIVITY DatabaseHelper)
  public void delete() {

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS mylist_data");
    onCreate(db);

}
```

(NA ACTIVITY MainActivity)
(Em cima)
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
DatabaseHelper myDB;
Button button, button4, button2, button5;
EditText editText, editText2, editText3, editText4;
```

(Em baixo na hora de chamar o metodo)

button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

```
        myDB.delete();
```

Comment: Você referenciou o button2? button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2); Nao vi no seu codigo acima.

Answer (score 0):

Não testei seu código mas olhando para:

`db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS mylist_data");`

Parece que você está colocando IF antes de TABLE.

O correto seria:

`db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mylist_data");`